# How does materializecss handle validation?

Tags: html, validation, materialize

I can't find any documentation detailing how validation works on materializecss.

I'm trying to validate a from consisting of input fields and radio groups and it isn't working.

Does anyone have a working example of how to validate a form using SELECT, radio and other form input field types with Materializecss?

Comment: There is no such default feature in `Materializecss` to validate SELECT, radio and other form input field types (but only email), you need validation plugin, good choice will be jQuery Validation Plugin.

Comment: I see, thanks for the confirmation. They touch on validation on the examples and I thought I was missing something on how that worked.